# Is libpng12.dll not compatible with Win7 (64-bits)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll, regsvr32, libpng

I use libpng package in VisualStudio 2008 to read the png images and my program has to use the libpng12.dll. I putted the libpng12.dll in Windows\System32 and Windows\SysWOW64 and wanted to use regsvr32.exe to register it, but it didn't work so my program also cannot use it. How can I fix it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the DLL needs to be registered?

Comment: regsvr32.exe only works works COM components. Normal dlls does not need to (and cannot) be registered with regsvr32.exe.

Comment: And please DON'T, I repeat, DON'T mess around with Windows system folders - this was cause of the well-known DLL hell situation. Just put the dll in the same folder where your executable resides. Don't forget that there may be other applications installed on the machine needing a different revision of libpng12.dll than yours.

Comment: @fefe - [Wrong](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/11/17/10237911.aspx)!

Answer (score 0):

DLL's have to match the bit-ness of the EXE. A 64 bits EXE can only use 64 bits DLLs, and a 32 bits EXE can only use 32 bits DLLs. (Barring out-of-process COM components, but that's irrelevant here).

BTW, the normal tool to fix DLL problems is [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com).